# Redirect entire bash session to log file

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I am familiar with the ability to pipe and redirect the IO of individual processes when running them in bash. However, is there a way to redirect stdio for an entire bash session?

Ideally, I would like to transparently pipe all `stdout` and `stderr` of all processes spawned by bash into `tee` to duplicate into a file the printed output displayed to the user. No matter what processes are run within that bash session, I could then go back later and look over the output.

Even more ideally, this should be the case for simple interactive programs that take options from stdin, but not for heavily interactive programs like vim.

The best I've found so far is: whenever the user opens a new terminal, run the command:

```
bash --login -i > >(tee ~/bash_$$.log) 2>&1
```

This will immediately start an interactive child shell in that new shell, and `tee` all `stdin` and `stderr` to a logfile named with the new parent shell's PID (to avoid overwriting).

This works, but `vim` fails to start with `Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal`. Are there any known solutions, up to and including patching the shell, to do this?

Comment: What good would patching the shell do when it's `vim` that has the behavior you don't want?

Comment: `vim >& /dev/pts/<id>` :)

Comment: well, sure, but presumably the OP doesn't want the log to be evaded. :)

Comment: or maybe: `alias vim='vim >& $(tty)'`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah, but it's just an idea... i don't really know what OP effectively wants :)

Comment: BTW, I'd argue that if you're asking about how to implement logging that works with TTY-centric apps, as opposed to how to implement in-place file-descriptor-level in-place redirection, this is a system administration question as opposed to a software development question, and would be better at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @pah, ...hmm. That alias would actually work for bash, since it allows redirections in any position, but for a more POSIX-y shell where redirections are only guaranteed to be supported in the first and last positions, one might need `alias vim='>"$(tty)" 2>&1 vim'` instead to avoid forming an illegal command when passing a file to edit as an argument. Or `vim() { command vim "$@" >"$(tty)" 2>&1; }`, of course.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy well noted!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Background***: `vim` is failing because `isatty()` is returning false when given the file descriptor for stdout; this is a safeguard to prevent uses such as `vim >file` that generally don't make sense. (Also, there are operating system calls available for interacting with PTYs that are useful to graphical, cursor-oriented programs that aren't available with a simple FIFO; this is why tools like `ssh` go to the trouble to provide a pseudoterminal during interactive use).

What's important for your purposes is that *`vim` is directly inspecting the file descriptor it's passed as stdout*. The shell is not a party to this -- it's literally `vim` running a standard-C-library call that gets some details about an open file descriptor -- so it's nothing that patching or reconfiguring the shell can fix.

To avoid this, then, you need to find a different way to redirect your output for logging such that stdout and stderr are still pointed at PTYs.

---

That said, for your *real* goal (logging all activity, vs redirecting stdout in-place), what you want is probably `script`:

```
if [ -z "$redirection_done" ]; then
  redirection_done=1 exec script shell.log bash --login -i
fi
```

Using logging support from another tool which simulates a TTY, such as `screen` or `tmux`, will likewise suffice. (`unbuffer`, from the `expect` toolkit, can be used with similar effect).

---

***Back to your literal question...*** (since while it may not be what you want to know, it *is* what you asked):

In all POSIX shells, including bash,

```
exec >wherever
```

...will immediately redirect stdout for the current shell to `wherever`. This can be a process substitution in bash, as anywhere else; thus, in an already-running shell, you can execute

```
exec > >(tee shell.log) 2>&1
```

Comment: That is possibly useful for simplifying the redirection, but it causes the same problem when trying to run `vim`. I need the redirection to be as transparent as possible to the user so they don't want to turn it off.

Comment: Well, yes, vim cares if the output isatty(). You can't fix that, and it's not bash's problem. Do your logging with `screen` or `tmux` or such.

Comment: ...`script` can likewise be used to log while retaining `isatty()`, because it's doing the same hackery screen/tmux/etc are.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for. The question kind of evolved with research between the time I wrote the title and finished the body.